# Will invoking supertype methods create a new supertype object?

Tags: java, oop

Given the code snippet:

```
class A {
    public String foo() {

    }
}

class B extends A {
    public String foo() {
        super.foo();
    }
}
```

What happens when we invoke:

```
B b = new B();
b.foo();
```

Is the `A` object internally created, just to call `A.foo()`?

Comment: Well, it depends. A's constructor does run and memory for A is allocated. So I would say yes, A is created. But it's part of B, so there is no dedicated A for your B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.** You don't create any other object.

When you extend a class and instantiate the child you have already created an object that is supertype instance plus your extended stuff.
Although you don't actually create two separate objects, you create one that is both (`B is A++`) which is also known as *polymorphism* (you have an object that can execute supertype methods).

Answer (score 2):

the `super.method()` syntax disables the regular dynamic method dispatch mechanism and explicitly calls the method defined for this object's superclass, passing in the same `this` reference. No instantiation is involved.

Answer (score 0):

`A` instance is created once `new B();` is called. Remember, that derived classes are in `is-a` relation with parent class. Here, one can say, that `B` `is-a` `A`.